# OpenMP 4 simd vectorization for c=c+a*b

Tags: c++, openmp, simd

I do not know if OpenMP  4 support this for loop or not. The speed with and without the `pragma` is the same.

```
#pragma omp  for simd
for (size_t i = 0; i < col; i++)
{
    C[i] += A[i]* B[i];
}
```

Comment: What compiler options did you use? What compiler? What OS? What hardware. `omp simd` is rather pointless in my opinion with x86 compilers due to auto-vectorization.  GCC uses auto-vectorization with `-O3`. Try comparing with and without using SIMD with `-O2`.  What size is `col`. If it's very large then this operations is memory bandwidth bound anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The reason (I guess) for the pragma do be of no effect is double:

- The code vectorises already without the `simd` directive; and
- The code is memory bound anyway, so adding more threads to compute it won't make much differences unless it gives you access to more memory bandwidth. See [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11579987/5239503) for more details.